# Getting unexpected output from the swing program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, translucency

In the following code why i'm  getting an invisible window?What does 
`setUndecorated()` do and where it is used for.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class UsingJLayer {

UsingJLayer()
{
    JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Picasa Viewer");
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    jfrm.setSize(dim);
    jfrm.setUndecorated(true);
    jfrm.setBackground(new Color(0,100,0,0));


    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new UsingJLayer();}});

}
```

}

Secondly if i comment out `jfrm.setUndecorated(true)` and instead use `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);` then i get a translucent window as expected.
So,what is `setUndecorated()` and `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`.I have to use one of them as otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: What part of the javadoc of those methods do you not understand ?

Comment: It says for setUndecorated()"This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable. To make this frame decorated, it must be opaque and have the default shape, otherwise the IllegalComponentStateException will be thrown."
I'm confused as it says to make it decorated,it must have default shape and opaque then what if we want to even change the shape as well as opacity.
In other words,i'm not clear what is the use of "setUndecorated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetUndecorated is called on a frame to remove The title bar/maximize button/ etc. Here is a good example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#shaped